# How to sync SQL Server Logins with database User after a restore from another server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, restore

I have a database server with several databases inside. This server is used as **test server** to store a set of **test databases**. The **test databases** do not come from the same **production server** thus I can have a mixed context where multiple **test databases** in **test server** come from different **production servers**. The logins and the mapped users in all the production servers have the same name but indeed their login passwords are different.

I use a Powershell Azure CLI script in order to copy the **production databases** from their **source production server** and restore them in the unique **target test database**.

The issue is that there is an inconsistent state between the mapping of the logins in the test server and the user in the test database, since even though they got the same name their identifier is probably different.

How can I map the test server login password to each user in the databases by using the **name as a matching criteria**?

Comment: When you create the login(s) on the second server you should be specifying it's SID; this means that the users in the restored database aren't orphaned. If the logins already exist, and already have different SIDs, you'll need to `ALTER` the users so that they are linked to the right `LOGIN`; which presumably is the one with the same name (though this is not always the case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a shorthand way to 'Auto\_Fix' all Orphaned Users in an SQL Server 2008 R2 database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/is-there-a-shorthand-way-to-auto-fix-all-orphaned-users-in-an-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2):

As the databases user are identical across the servers, you can simply maintain the SID same for the logins across all the SQL Servers while the purpose of the login/users is same. Following is an example to create login with same SID, this is onetime activity across the servers (while you aware of server level permissions).

```
create login test_login_1 with password = 'MyStrongPassword', sid = 0x76CED6A5F3FA0000378945348A64FB67;
```

Alternatively, as an extension to your existing PowerShell script, you can use [Copy-DbaLogin](https://docs.dbatools.io/Copy-DbaLogin) from dbatools.io to replicate the logins.

Answer (score 0):

There is `sp_change_users_login` stored procedure in SQL sever, which can be used for this purpose.

More information on [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55714/22336).